# Объединить две матрицы

Tags: java

Есть две матрицы:

```
int[][] one = {{ 1, 1, 1 },
               { 0, 0, 0 }, 
               { 0, 0, 0 }};
int[][] two = {{ 0, 0, 1 },
               { 0, 1, 0 }, 
               { 1, 0, 0 }};
```

Нужно их объединить, сместив вторую относительно первой на offset:

```
merge(int[][] one, int[][] two, Point offset)
```

Например, offset = new Point(2,-2);

Результат:

```
int[][] result = {{0,0,0,0,1},
                  {0,0,0,1,0},
                  {1,1,1,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0}}
```

Матрицы могут быть разной размерности, смещение отрицательным.
Пока смог реализовать только объединение матриц разной размерности, без смещения:

```
public int[][] merge( int[][] one, int[][] two, Point offset ) {
    int[][] merged = getEmptyMergedMatrix( one, two, offset  );
    addToMatrix( matrix, one, offset  );
    addToMatrix( matrix, two, offset );
    return merged;
}

private int[][] getEmptyMergedMatrix( int[][] one, int[][] two, Point offset ) {
    int height = Math.max( one.length, two.length );
    //int height = Math.max( one.length, two.height + Math.abs( offset.y ) );
    int width = Math.max( one[0].length, two[0].length );
   // int width = Math.max( one[0].length, two[0].length + Math.abs( offset.x );
    return new int[][]( height, width );
}

private void addToMatrix( int[][] dest, int[][] src, Point offset ) {
    int srcHeight = src.length;
    int srcWidth = src[ 0 ].length;

    for ( int y = 0; y < srcHeight; y++ ) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < srcWidth; x++ ) {
            if ( src[ y ][ x ] == 1 ) dest[ y ][ x ] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Если раскомментировать строки в 3-ем методе - получается матрица правильного размера для любых смещений. Но не могу сообразить, как скопировать значения со смещенной матрицы. Есть какие-нибудь идеи?